# ExtJS getCmp Panel by id doesn't serialize?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

unfortunately I wasn't able to find any useful info about getting 'Ext.tab.Panel' by id. I'll be more specific with a source:


I'm defining a panel to work with:

```
Ext.define('MyMobileApp.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
xtype: 'main',
id: 'mainTabPanel',
....
```

In currently active view, which is contained in this panel I created a button and put a handler on it:

```
xtype: 'button',
text: 'Switch View',    
handler: function () {
    var main = Ext.getCmp('mainTabPanel'); //.getActiveTab();
    main.setActiveTab(Ext.getCmp('AnotherView'));
...
```

Where 'AnotherView' is id of a view which is also part of the panel.

But i'm getting error when trying to 'setActiveTab':

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setActiveTab'
```

Looks like extjs is finding an object, but can't serialize? 
 
All I want to do is switch views by custom buttons handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ist, that the Tab Panel doesn't have the function `'setActiveTab'`

You have to use `'setActiveItem'` instead.

Sencha Touch 2 Api: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-setActiveItem

```
xtype: 'button',
text: 'Switch View',    
handler: function () {
    var main = Ext.getCmp('mainTabPanel'); //.getActiveTab();
    main.setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp('AnotherView'));
    //main.setActiveItem(1); //You can also set the new item with the index of it
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for quick and very helpful reply. It appears I was looking for the wrong documentation for ExtJS 4.1 (not the sencha 2.1)